# Facebook Invalid Redirect URI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to develop on my local machine.  I've set the facebook Site URL to

```
http://localhost:8000
```

My Login Code:

```
function tryFBLogin() {
   FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log("User is connected to the application.");
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            return  http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('http://localhost:8000/page/'))
        } else {
            console.log("Something messed up in facebook login");
        }
    });
}
```

When I click the login butt on I get this error message:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirect parameter has to match the domain for the app.

Set app domain blank, and the site url to the root of the link you are displaying.

```
App Domain: 
Site URL: http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: I tried this, still getting the same error code-- By redirect parameter matching domain, you're suggesting I set App Domain blank, and then the HttpResponseRedirect's url is something like (reverse('/page')) ?  Thanks for help-